# How do I modify/subset a wget script to specify a date range to only download certain years into different scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, date, download, wget

I am trying to download a lot of data for some research from the CMIP6 website (https://esgf-node.llnl.gov/search/cmip6/) that provides wget scripts for each model.

The scripts are for every 6 hours or month from 1850 to 2014. The date format looks like this (*1st script*): **185001010600-185101010000** or (for *2nd script*) **195001010600-195002010000, 195002010600-195003010000**

---

***My goal is to turn one giant script into several smaller ones with five years each for 1980 to 2015***

**As an example, I would want to subset the main script into different scripts with 5 year intervals ("19800101-19841231" then "19850101-19901231", etc.) with each named wget-1980_1985.sh, wget-1985_1990.sh, respectively**

***For an example date range for the 2nd script, I would need:
197912010600 through 198601010000, then every 5 years after that***

---

I'm a beginner so please help if you can!

Part of the wget script format for each file looks like this (it won't let me copy and paste the whole thing since there are too many links [see below to find the file yourself]):

> 1.) #These are the embedded files to be downloaded download_files="$(cat <185001010600-185101010000.nc' 'http://esgf-data2.diasjp.net/thredds/fileServer/esg_dataroot/CMIP6/CMIP/MIROC/MIROC6/historical/r1i1p1f1/6hrPlevPt/hus/gn/v20191204/hus_6hrPlevPt_MIROC6_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_185001010600-185101010000.nc' 'SHA256'
>   'fa9ac4149cc700876cb10c4e681173bcc0040ea03b9a439d1c66ef47b0253c5a'
>   'hus_6hrPlevPt_MIROC6_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_**185101010600-185201010000**.nc' 'http://esgf-data2.diasjp.net/thredds/fileServer/esg_dataroot/CMIP6/CMIP/MIROC/MIROC6/historical/r1i1p1f1/6hrPlevPt/hus/gn/v20191204/hus_6hrPlevPt_MIROC6_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_185101010600-185201010000.nc' 'SHA256'
>   '4ef4f99aa34aae6dfdafaa4aab206344125abe7808df675d688890825db53047'
>
> 2.) For the second script, the dates look like this: 'ps_6hrLev_MIROC6_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_**195001010600-195002010000**.nc'

To run it, you just download the script from the website (see below)

---

**or downloading from this link should work:** 
1.) https://esgf-node.llnl.gov/esg-search/wget/?distrib=false&dataset_id=CMIP6.CMIP.MIROC.MIROC6.historical.r1i1p1f1.6hrPlevPt.hus.gn.v20191204|esgf-data2.diasjp.net

2.) A similar script can be seen here (the dates are different but I need this one too): 
https://esgf-node.llnl.gov/esg-search/wget/?distrib=false&dataset_id=CMIP6.CMIP.MIROC.MIROC6.historical.r1i1p1f1.6hrLev.ps.gn.v20191114|esgf-data2.diasjp.net

---

to run the script in the terminal, this is the command i use

> bash wget* -H

and it will download each file.

I can vi the script and delete each file (by using "dd") I don't need but this will be extremely time consuming.

---

To find this data and get the wget script from the website, go to: https://esgf-node.llnl.gov/search/cmip6/

and select the variables on the left side of the page as follows:
Source ID: MIROC6,
Experiment ID: Historical,
Variant Label: r1i1p1f1,
Table ID: 6hrPlevPt,
and Variable: hus
[it will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPvmq.png)

***If these files are too big, you can also select Frequency:monthly instead for a much smaller file. I just want you to see the date format since monthly is just the month and year**

Then hit search and it will give you one model to download. [it will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmrCu.png)On the bottom, with the links, it will say "wget script." Click that and it will download.

You can

> vi wget*

to view and/or edit it or

> bash wget* -H

to run/download each file. 
It might ask you to log in but I've found typing in nonsense to the username and password still starts the download.

---

Please help! This will be the next 6 months of my life and I really don't want to "dd" every file I don't need for all of these!

Comment: 1) You are deleting files with *dd*?? Why?
2) Can you simplify your problem with a minimum verifiable explanation?

Comment: @MatiasBarrios they mean the `dd` keystroke sequence inside `vi`

Comment: jhnc is correct, I meant within vi. To simplify my issue: I have a very big wget script for multiple years that I need to subset into many different scripts for 5 years each

Comment: "19800101-19851231" then "19850101-19901231" ? One of those 1985s should be either 1984 or 1986

Comment: woops, sorry about that (haven't slept lately!) you're right, I meant "19800101-19841231" then "19850101-19901231"

Comment: what about the other ranges? eg. 1979-1986 is more than 5 years

Comment: I would only need 1979 because the file that begins 1980 is "197901010600-198001010000" then the next one starts 6 hours later, which is "198001010600-198101010000" and so on. So, I need something the range: 198001010000 to 201401010000 with the files like (doesn't have to be exact): 1979, 1980-1985 or 1979-1985; 1985-1990; 1990-1995; 1995-2000; 2000-2005; 2005-2010; and 2010-2014 (don't need 2015). I really appreciate the script you posted!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `bash` `for` loop can generate relevant date ranges and output filename.

A simple `sed` script can delete relevant lines if they appear in order.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

in=esgf_script

for y in $(seq 1979 5 2014); do
    out="wget_{$y}-$((y+4)).sh"
    sed '/_gn_/{               # if some kind of url:
        /_gn_'$((y+5))'/,$  d; #   delete if year >= y+5
        /_gn_2015/,$        d; #   delete if year >= 2015
        /_gn_'$y'/,$       !d; #   delete if year < y
    }' <"$in" >"$out"
done
```

The `seq` command generates every fifth year starting from 1979 up to 2014.

The `sed` script:

- looks for lines containing urls: `/_gn_/`
- deletes if year is too big
- otherwise, doesn't delete if year is big enough

This code assumes that:

- no lines except urls contain the first regex (`/_gn_/`)
- the urls appear in ascending year order (eg. urls containing 1994 cannot appear before ones containing 1993)

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you. This is very close to what I need! How would I modify it to give me scripts for: from 198001010000 to 201401010000 (so hours, day, month, and year)? And to break up the years into something like: 1980-1985; 1985-1990; 1990-1995; 1995-2000; 2000-2005; 2005-2010; and 2010-2014 (don't need 2015)?

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much!!! Very much appreciated